# how to compare 2 columns in 2 tables using SAS

Tags: sas, compare

there are 2 similar columns (x1 vs x2) in 2 tables a1, a2. How can I match and lineup them?
I tried compare function, but failed.

```
data a1;
input x1 $15.;
cards;
abcd
go shopping
DUT univarsity 
he is driving 
;
run;
data a2;
input x2 $15.;
 cards;
golf shopping
she is driving
abcdf
DUT univars 
;
run;
```

and I want the final table with matched values:

```
abcd               abcdf
go shopping        golf shopping
DUT univarsity     DUT univars
he is driving      she is driving
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will not scale well, but you get the idea. Use COMPGED to find the nearest match and take the minimum. This doesn't deal with cases where you don't have a good match.

You're essentially doing fuzzy matching which is a computationally intensive process.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.x1, t2.x2 
from a1 as t1, a2 as t2
group by t1.x1
having compged(x1, x2) = min(compged(x1, x2));
quit;
```

Comment: I tried COMPGED but your approach worked better , thanks Reeza!